# Why do I get a 'unidentified identifier' when accessing a structure member using my auto_ptr style class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using C++ templates to gain access to memory holding preferences. The memory is referenced by handles. To lock/unlock this memory, I written a auto_ptr like class template. When I wan't to access one of the members, the compiler issues a 'unidentified identifier" error.

```
typedef struct
{
    int value   ;

} PREFS ;

template <class T>
class PluginMem
{
    private :

    T       *ptr    ;

    public :

    T *
    operator ->
    (
    )
    {
        return( ptr ) ;
    }
} ;

typedef PluginMem<PREFS>    Prefs   ;

class   PluginContext
{
    public :

    template <class T>
    T *
    getNamedPreferences
    (
        const char  *prefsname
    ) ;

} ;

static void
test()
{
    PluginContext   ctx ;
    Prefs       *p  ;

    p = ctx.getNamedPreferences<Prefs>( "test" ) ;

    /*
     *  unidentified identifier 'value'
     */
    p->value = 0 ;
}
```

I expected to be able to change p->value to zero here.

Comment: It does not make much sense to use pointer to smart pointer. Who own the top pointer?

Comment: What do you mean with 'top pointer'?

Comment: Since you have a pointer to a smart pointer, the top one would be the first that appears in the chain (that is `Prefs       *p`). Next pointer would be the one returned by `operator->`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(*p)->value
```

Your `p` is just a pointer, you need first to dereference it so you can use your class `operator->`

Note - if you want to skip the dereference part, you will need to copy `Prefs` by value and use it without pointer notation (like `Prefs p`). Notice that you usually write `auto_ptr<foobar> baz` and not `auto_ptr<foobar> * baz`

Comment: `auto_ptr` is obsolete stuff. If you want to give a comparison, then you should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Originally I tried something like p = ctx.getNamedPreferences<<PluginMem,PREFS>> but the compiler complains about a bad template definition.

Comment: If I change Prefs *p to Prefs p, ctx.getNamedPreferences() needs to return a T & correct?

Comment: @EugèneBindels No, you just return T (copying it by value). There is only one field in T which is pointer type, copying it is not more costly than copying pointer itself